# clang's python binding throws an exception when get_children is called

Tags: python, parsing, clang

I'm trying to run an example found [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang), but it always fails to execute. After some debugging, I found out that the node.get_children() causes the exception, and here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 314, in 'calling callback function'
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\clang\cindex.py", line 1383, in visitor
children.append(child)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I'm using LLVM 4.0.1 on Windows, and I installed clang via pip (tried both clang3.5 and clang4.0.post1).

Here's my LD_LIBRARY_PATH: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin, which I added into my
PATH like this: %LD_LIBRARY_PATH%;%PYTHONPATH%;...rest of path...

I got the same error after installing LLVM5.0 and cloning clang from github.

**EDIT: I used Python2.7, but after switching to Python 3.6.3 everything works ok.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to Python 3.6 solved the problem.